# Laravel 5.1 Middleware caching doesn't catch Route-Model bindings

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I've got a middleware setup that's caching the HTML output of each public Controller request, in each of my controllers' __construct method.

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
    $this->middleware('cache.get', ['only' => 'show']);
    $this->middleware('cache.put', ['only' => 'show']);
}
```

The caching is working great, as expected, except for one thing: I've got Route-Model bindings setup in RouteServiceProvider.php for easy accessiblity of models in their respective controllers, like

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    $router->bind('posts', function($id) {
       return \App\Article::findBySlugOrIdOrFail($id);
    });

    $router->bind('tags', function($name) {
        return \App\Tag::where('name', $name)->firstOrFail();
    });

    $router->bind('artists', function($slug) {
        return \App\Artist::findBySlugOrIdOrFail($slug);
    });
```

Basically what's happening is even when pages are cached, I'm still getting a single query for each route where it's looking up that slug (SluggableInterface) or id. Wondering if there's a way to do this where the query doesn't occur when a route is cached? Or is that just not possible?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's my caching middleware:

```
class GetCache
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $key = StringHelper::keygen($request->path());

        if (Cache::has($key) && Auth::guest()) {
            $content=Cache::get($key);
            return response($content);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}


class PutCache
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $key = StringHelper::keygen($request->path());

        if (! Cache::has($key) && Auth::guest()) {
            Cache::put($key, $response->getContent(), 600);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to share your caching middleware?

Comment: @marcus.ramsden good point, added that in an edit above.

Comment: Updated it, realized I put my old cache filter up, instead of the middleware.

Comment: Hmm was wondering if it was something in your middleware carrying on when not needed but that looks OK to me.

Comment: Yeah, I think the route binding is just triggering before the controllers are even constructed, which makes sense. I saw somewhere earlier today that you can actually cache the route binding itself, but it seems like things could get tricky with separate caches.